# One word for "did not join"

Tags: single-word-requests

One word for "did not join"

Abstain is not appropriate to the sentence.
The word refers to a revolution.

Comment: refrained from...

Comment: '[skipped](https://www.google.nl/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22skipped+the+revolution%22)'

Comment: Skipped the revolution does not sound good.

Comment: @Stannis So, not only would you like one word, _one_ word only, but you _also_ want it to [sound](https://youtu.be/jr0JaXfKj68) good? :)

Comment: I meant appropriate. Sorry.

Comment: How about a two-word phrase - *sat out*.

Comment: What is the sentence you are talking about? That will help get you a better answer.

Comment: *Peter's brother **remained neutral** in the revolution.*  Or ***he avoided taking sides** in the revolution*.  Or *he avoided choosing a side*.  Or *he did his best to **stay out** of the revolution*. Maybe he ***did not take part [or participate] in** the rev*.  We could change the point of view:  *The revolution **passed Peter's brother by.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [shun?](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shun)

> **shun**
>
> verb (used with object), shunned, shunning.
>
> 1. to keep away from (a place, person, object, etc.), from motives of dislike, caution, etc.; take pains to avoid.

As is often the case, it depends on the context. Somebody might shun the revolution out of dislike for its aims, whereas he might avoid the revolution if he didn't want to take part for some other reason.